# Is it possible to combine Group by, Having and Sum?

Tags: sql, group-by, having

I have a table:

```
------------------------
|id|p_id|desired|earned|
------------------------
|1 | 1  |  5    |  7   |
|2 | 1  |  15   |  0   |
|3 | 1  |  10   |  0   |
|4 | 2  |  2    |  3   |
|5 | 2  |  2    |  3   |
|6 | 2  |  2    |  3   |
------------------------
```

I need to make some calculations, and try to make it in one not really complex request, otherwise I know how to calculate it with numbers of requests.
I need resulted table like following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
|p_id|total_earned|    AVG   |      Count     |  SUM    |
|    |            | (desired)|(if earned != 0)|(desired)|
---------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |      7     |     10   |       1        |    30   |
|  2 |      9     |      2   |       3        |    6    |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

I build so far:

```
SELECT p_id, SUM(earned), AVG(desired), Sum(desired) 
FROM table GROUP BY p_id
```

But I can't figure out how to calculate the number of grouped records with conditions. I can get this number with `HAVING` but in separated request.

I almost sure what SQL should have this power.

Comment: I use Postgres, but I search for universal solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `CASE` expression for this.

Try this,

```
SELECT p_id
    ,SUM(earned) AS total_earned
    ,AVG(desired) AS avg_desired
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN Earned!=0 THEN 1 END) AS earned_count
    ,SUM(desired) AS sum_desired
FROM table
GROUP BY p_id;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have almost done your query just add conditional aggregation with help of `case` expression for earned  count

```
SELECT 
           p_id,
           SUM(earned) [total_earned],
           AVG(desired) [desired],
           SUM(CASE WHEN earned <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [COUNT],
           SUM(desired) [SUM] FROM <table>
 GROUP BY p_id
```

Result

```
p_id    total_earned  desired   COUNT  SUM
1       7             10        1      30
2       9             2         3      6
```

Comment: That is non-standard SQL

Comment: Invalid syntax for Postgres (or standard SQL).

Answer (score 3):

A shorter alternative to `CASE` is

```
SELECT p_id,
    SUM(earned) AS total_earned,
    AVG(desired) AS average_desired,
    COUNT(earned != 0 OR NULL) AS earned_count,
    SUM(desired) AS sum_desired
FROM table GROUP BY p_id;
```

because `NULL`s are not counted.

Answer (score 1):

[**`NULLIF()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF) is standard SQL and probably shortest:

```
SELECT p_id
     , count(NULLIF(earned, 0)) AS earned_count
  -- , more ...
FROM   table
GROUP  BY 1;
```

`count()` only counts non-null values.

More variants:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/for-absolute-performance-is-sum-faster-or-count/27572#27572)